# IntelliJ IDEA consuming lots of CPU

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I upgraded from IntelliJ IDEA from 12 CE to 13 CE few days ago and it has been hogging up CPU. Every few minutes it'll peak to 450-500% and then come down to 100-200%. Also, I've upgraded my Scala plugin to 0.30.380. Not sure what's causing the issue!?

Comment: So I checked, it wasn't doing any indexing whatsoever, which may be a general cause of intermittent high CPU usage. It just needed some more memory to prevent repeated garbage collection. I found the file idea.vmoptions and increased the memory for InteiiJ to run (Xms = 512m and Xmx = 2048). The CPU usage has come down to 0.2 - 10% when nothing is being done on it.

Comment: Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, IntelliJ Scala plugin has some performance problems. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6082 for example.

Comment: @ziggystar I wish I could, reputation <10, so no can;t do.

Comment: @ghik Thanks for the resource. But this issue is on previous version of IntelliJ and older scala plugin version. But maybe it has carried over in newer versions too.

Comment: @KP I didn't see it marked as fixed, so...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm posting this comment by K P as an answer, because K P does not have enough reputation.

> It just needed some more memory to prevent repeated garbage collection. I found the file idea.vmoptions [aka idea64.exe.vmoptions] and increased the memory for InteiiJ to run (Xms = 512m and Xmx = 2048). The CPU usage has come down to 0.2 - 10% when nothing is being done on it.

Comment: helpful doc, on how to do it: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/increasing-memory-heap.html and this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: For those who use Idea on MacOSx see: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tuning-intellij-idea.html

Comment: huh? How can you ever not have enough rep to post an answer?

Comment: Mac OS X users: make sure that you update the settings in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/idea.vmoptions not /Applications/IntelliJIdeaXX.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions because the first one is preferred.

Comment: $ cat /usr/lib/idea-IC-171.3780.107/bin/idea.vmoptions
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine

Answer (score 3):

Go to your home folder, then navigate to `.IntelliJIdea13\config\options`

Edit the file `project.default.xml` by changing the `VM_PARAMETERS` `Xmx` and `Xms` as follows:

`<option name="VM_PARAMETERS" value="-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -ea" />`

It decreased the CPU usage to 50%.

Answer (score 2):

Try clean up cache and restart. In Intellij 14 go to menu File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 1):

As other said,increasing memory heap of IDEA is work, my IDEA version is 2016.3.4, following is setting way

> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Use the main menu command Help | Edit Custom VM Options to create a copy of the idea.vmoptions file in the user home. Refer to Edit Custom VM Options for details.
>    - Copy the existing file from the IntelliJ IDEA installation folder somewhere and save the path to this location in the environment variable IDEA_VM_OPTIONS.
>    - Copy the existing file /bin/idea.exe.vmoptions or /bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions from the IntelliJ IDEA installation folder into the location under your user home.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's wondering the "right" way to edit the idea.vmoptions or idea64.vmoptions file, here it is: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tuning-intellij-idea.html

On *NIX, you want to copy

```
<IntelliJ IDEA installation folder>/bin/idea64.vmoptions
```

to:

```
$HOME/.IntelliJIdeaXX/idea64.vmoptions
```

and edit that file to increase the heap memory for IntelliJ IDEA

(OP's example settings: Xms = 512m and Xmx = 2048)