# IntelliJ IDEA hogging CPU without doing anything

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA is using 100% of all CPUs without seemingly doing anything. This occurs whenever I'm doing something in it, e.g. I type a letter on my keyboard and there is significant lag before it appears on the screen. I tried invalidating caches and restarting, I tried rebooting, reinstalling, [increasing memory for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21599618/4490400), etc.

How can I make IntelliJ IDEA usable again? Is there any way to debug what it's doing when it's consuming these resources?

Comment: Please refer to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235 and report the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: try to remove all cache files

Comment: Maybe in your project you have lots of library files (like node_modules, gwt cache, etc) and IDEA tries to index them? This could explain a lag I think. If it's the case you can mark those files as excluded in Project Settings > Modules.

Comment: When IDEA is indexing, there is a "process running" indicator and when you click it, it says "indexing". This issue occurs when IDEA is giving no indication that anything at all would be happening.